# shell script to read directory names and create .txt files with the same names in another directory

Tags: linux, shell

I have two directories, one called clients and another called test, inside the directory called clients I have some folders, I need a shell script that reads the name of the folders inside clients and creates .txt files with the same name inside the folder test, I am very new to shell and I have no idea how to do this, could you guys help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `xargs` with `ls`. `ls -F` displays all files in the directory `client`, but then displays the folders with an extra `/` at the end. the `grep` uses the extra `/` in the output of `ls -F` to only pass folders to the next command. Then, `sed 's/\///g` removes the extra `/` from grep, and passes the names to xargs. xargs will then pass the folders to the `%` symbol, and then make text files with the names.

```
ls -F client | grep / | sed 's/\///g' |  xargs -I % touch tests/%.txt
```

Comment: Thank you friend, it worked out better than I could imagine, and thanks for the detailed explanation

Comment: Great solution. I would like to offer a bash alternative: `for i in client/*/; do touch tests/$(basename $i).txt; done`. First, we iterate only over directories within client instead of all files, then we use `basename` to get the directory name without trailing slash (and, without parent directory).